# Symlink to file which does not exist yet

Tags: shell-script, osx, symlink

I'm currently trying to cleanup my home directory by moving files like `.vimrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc. to a directory `.dotfiles` in my home directory.

The idea is to use symbolic links to these files afterwards:
`ln -s ~/.dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.`
 This works quiet fine, but I'd like to automate this process by writing *my first* bash script and I ran into some trouble.

The script currently looks something like this:

```
#!//bin/bash
# Make script executable with: chmod u+x brew.sh

# Ask for the administrator password upfront.
sudo -v

# Keep-alive: update existing `sudo` time stamp until the script has finished.
while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &

# Create '.other'-folder
echo "--> ~/.other"
if [ -d ~/.other ];
then
  echo "Directory ~/.other exists..."
else
  echo "Creating directory ~/.other..."
  mkdir ~/.other
fi
echo ""

# TRASH
echo "--> ~/.Trash"
if [ -d ~/.Trash ];
then
  echo "Directory ~/.Trash does exists. Moving it to ~/.other..."
  mv ~/.Trash ~/.other/
else
  echo "Directory ~/.Trash doesn't exists. Creating it in ~/.other..."
  mkdir ~/.other/.Trash
fi

echo "Linking ~/.other/.Trash to ~/.Trash..."
ln -s ~/.other/.Trash ~/.
echo ""

# BASH_HISTORY
echo "--> ~/.bash_history"
if [ -a ~/.bash_history ];
then
  echo "File ~/.bash_history does exists. Moving it to ~/.other..."
  mv ~/.bash_history ~/.other/
else
  echo "File ~/.bash_history doesn't exists. Creating it in ~/.other..."
  touch ~/.other/.bash_history
fi

echo "Linking ~/.other/.bash_history to ~/.bash_history..."
ln -s ~/.other/.bash_history ~/.
echo ""

# BASH_SESSIONS
echo "--> ~/.bash_sessions"
if [ -d ~/.bash_sessions ];
then
  echo "Directory ~/.bash_history does exists. Moving it to ~/.other..."
  mv ~/.bash_sessions ~/.other/
else
  echo "Directory ~/.bash_history doesn't exists. Creating it in ~/.other..."
  mkdir ~/.other/.bash_sessions
fi

echo "Linking ~/.other/.bash_sessions/ to ~/.bash_sessions/..."
ln -s ~/.other/.bash_sessions ~/.
echo ""

# .LOCAL
echo "--> ~/.local"
if [ -d ~/.local ];
then
  echo "Directory ~/.local does exists. Moving it to ~/.other..."
  mv ~/.local ~/.other/
else
  echo "Directory ~/.local doesn't exists. Creating it in ~/.other..."
  mkdir ~/.other/.local
fi

echo "Linking ~/.other/.local/ to ~/.local/..."
ln -s ~/.other/.local ~/.
echo ""

# .CONFIG
echo "--> ~/.config"
if [ -d ~/.config ];
then
  echo "Directory ~/.config does exists. Moving it to ~/.other..."
  mv ~/.config ~/.other/
else
  echo "Directory ~/.config doesn't exists. Creating it in ~/.other..."
  mkdir ~/.other/.config
fi

echo "Linking ~/.other/.config/ to ~/.config/..."
ln -s ~/.other/.config ~/.
echo ""
```

As you can see the code is pretty repetitive, but first things first. The code should work roughly like this. Check whether file (for example `init.vim`) exists in my home directory. If it does exists move it to either `~/.other` (*not so important files*) or to `~/.dotfiles` (*important files*). If it doesn't exist create a file (or directory) in `~/.dotfiles` or `~/.other`. Symlink afterwards.

So far the theory. The problem is, if the file does't exist in my home-directory yet - the script just creates a file in `~/.dotfiles`/`~/.other`, and links the name in the home directory to it. This doesn't really work out in practice, since some files need specific permissions. For example `neovim` doesn't recognize some files if they are created with this script and it's not very efficient to just create the files before they are even used.

Is there a way to fix this (for example by creating a link, without creating the target file - I tried it once to link `.bash_history` to `.other/.bash_history`, the link worked fine, but `bash` couldn't write to a non existing file)? It would be optimal if new files would be **created** in the *right* place and I only need to specify the *right* place before?

PS: When the file already exists the script works fine (it just moved the file to the new location and links it).

Comment: You'll want to read about the `touch` command that will create the file if it doesn't exist, and `chmod` to give it the appropriate permissions

Comment: @glennjackman I do know about the touch command, but how should I know about what permissions I need to set? I'd need to research for every single file. There has to be a more easy way. I thought about aliasing the script to command like `cleanup` and it loops over all files in the home directory and asks the user if he wants to move it to `~/.dotfiles` or `~./other`, but then the user had to actually do something and had to execute the code multiple times (if knew files are added to the home directory - I can't prevent the creation in the home directory).

Comment: Unrelated but what's up with the sudo tricks at the start? Doesn't seem like your script needs elevated privs.

Comment: @Mat You are probably right, I just think one time I got `permission denied`, when I tried to create a dir. I'm honestly not sure about it. I should probably remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite to reduce duplication

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make script executable with: chmod u+x brew.sh

# Ask for the administrator password upfront.
sudo -v

# Keep-alive: update existing `sudo` time stamp until the script has finished.
while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &

# Create '.other'-folder
echo "--> ~/.other"
mkdir -p ~/.other 2>/dev/null
echo ""

create_dir() {
    local pathname=$1 destination=$2 permissions=$3
    local dirname=$(basename "$pathname")

    echo "--> $pathname"
    if [ -L "$pathname" ] && [ "$(dirname "$(readlink "$pathname")")" = "$destination" ]; then
        echo "$pathname is already a symbolic link to $destination/$filename"
        return
    elif [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
        echo "Directory $pathname exists. Moving it to $destination..."
        mv "$pathname" $destination/
    else
        echo "Directory $pathname doesn't exist Creating it in $destination..."
        mkdir -p "$destination/$dirname"
    fi
    chmod "$permissions" "$destination/$direname"

    echo "Linking $destination/$dirname to $pathname ..."
    (
        cd "$(dirname "$pathname")"
        ln -s "$destination/$dirname" 
    )
    echo
}

create_file() {
    local pathname=$1 destination=$2 permissions=$3
    local filename=$(basename "$pathname")
    echo "--> $pathname"
    if [ -L "$pathname" ] && [ "$(dirname "$(readlink "$pathname")")" = "$destination" ]; then
        echo "$pathname is already a symbolic link to $destination/$filename"
        return
    elif [ -a "$pathname" ]; then
        echo "File $pathname exists. Moving it to $destination..."
        mv "$pathname" $destination/
    else
        echo "File $pathname doesn't exists. Creating it in $destination..."
        touch "$destination/$filename"
    fi
    chmod "$permissions" "$destination/$filename"

    echo "Linking $destination/$filename to ~/.bash_history..."
    (
        cd "$(dirname "$pathname")"
        ln -s "$destination/$filename"
    )
    echo ""
}

create_dir   ~/.Trash          ~/.other  755   # TRASH
create_file  ~/.bash_history   ~/.other  600   # BASH_HISTORY
create_file  ~/.bash_sessions  ~/.other  644   # BASH_SESSIONS
create_dir   ~/.local          ~/.other  755   # .LOCAL
create_dir   ~/.config         ~/.other  755   # .CONFIG

create_file  ~/.bashrc         ~/.dotfiles 644 # etc ...
```

Notes:

- `mkdir -p` will create the directory if it does not exist
- check that the directory/file is not already a symbolic link first.
- if specific files require specific permissions, no choice but to specify it.

Comment: How did you find the needed permission so fast? This is honestly amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: I did an `ls -la` and noted what perms my files have.